# Regarding convert com port string to integer array

Tags: java, string

If the string is declared like this it works good

```
String str="179,206";            
String [] numbers = str.split(",");            
int[] ints = new int[numbers.length];
for(int i = 0;i < numbers.length;i++)
{   
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
```

while I read same string fromm com port using below code

```
serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(8);//Read 8 bytes from serial port
String str = new String(buffer);
```

and then use the previous code to convert to integer. Then it give below error
Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.NumberFormatException

: For input string: "179"
    at `java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)`
    at `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)`
    at `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)`
    at `simpleread.SimpleRead.main(SimpleRead.java:44)`

Comment: " 179" contains space in starting

Comment: you can add `trim()` to ommit spaces

Comment: Thanks I got the answer from below code using trim its working great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use `trim()` to remove leading/trailing blanks:

```
ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i].trim());
```

But a better solution is to remove spaces during the split:

```
String [] numbers = str.trim().split(" *, *");
```

This trims the whole string and the split regex gobbles up any spaces either side of commas, which means you can safely use the numbers later in your code without having to remember to `trim()` them before use, which is why I prefer this approach.